# Oracle SQL Developer ignores NLS when exporting

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having trouble getting SQL Developer (version 4.0.3.16) to apply date formatting when exporting data. I am attempting to export to SQL (i.e. insert statements).

I set the NLS date format to be DD-MON-RRRR HH24.MI.SS as below:

[image]

It seems to work okay for actually viewing data within the tool but when it exports to SQL, it reverts back to the default like so:

```
Insert into EMAIL_ADDRESS (EMAIL_ADDRESS_ID,USERID,ADDRESS,LAST_UPDATE_TS) values (100,'user','fake@email.org',to_date('24-AUG-08','DD-MON-RR'));
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your Windows date format set to? Check it in Control panel.

Comment: What is the version of your copy of SQL Developer? On mine (4.1.5.xxx) it works as expected, the automatically generated INSERT statements use the NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting.

Comment: @Littlefoot - why would the Windows date format matter? (I didn't even know such a thing existed.)

Comment: @LIttlefoot I can't actually look at the setting bc I don't have admin, but dates look like this: Friday, ‎February ‎23, ‎2018. I can't imagine that has anything to do with SQL DEveloper.

Comment: @mathguy 4.0.3.16. It could be that an update to 4.1 would help, but unfortunately, I can't install software on this computer :-(

Comment: OK. With some luck, Jeff Smith will see your question, perhaps he can help. It may (or may not) be something that was changed between versions.

Comment: I'm just guessing, @math. My TOAD goes wild and changes date format settings which are then reverted when I temporarily change Windows date format. I'm on a mobile phone now and can't try anything, but I thought that such a check won't take much time, especially if it helps.

Comment: `I can't install software on this computer` - you don't need to install. There is no installer, Download a ZIP file (there is no other), unpack it into any directory, and run it.

Comment: I'm away from my PC, but it should honor your date format. Will test asap.

Comment: @krokodilko - When an employer tells you "you are not allowed to install software on this machine", they generally mean downloading and unpacking from a zip file too - they don't mean *install* literally (as in, using an installer).

Comment: @mathguy when they tell me that, I know I've found the wrong job

Comment: @krokodilko - these days internet usage policies and download monitoring tools have got pretty strict. Even if it gets past the firewall, you or your boss might get a call from desktop security if you even attempt to download an executable to your PC in breach of the usage policy you signed. (I work for banks and they take desktop security rather seriously.)

Comment: @thatjeffsmith like there are loads of jobs to choose from :(

Comment: @WilliamRobertson ... turns, out there are. we're hiring. I'd never counsel someone to break their firms security rules. I would counsel devs to take jobs where they're given access to the tools they need to do their job though.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - I have had to fire employees who violated my firm's policies. The proper approach is to tell a manager what you need, prove very clearly why you need it, and get it done "the right way." Sometimes you won't be allowed to make the change for various reasons (although in this very specific case it is hard to see a legitimate reason not to upgrade). As to "got the wrong job" - with your experience and qualifications, you may have many more options than the OP. My solution to the same problem, instead of changing jobs, was to get to be "the boss" myself.

Comment: @mathguy i've never suggested anyone violate their firm's policies. I'm with you, on 'the right way. '

Comment: In a large organisation, it's not up to our line managers. There is an internet usage policy, a software request system, a desktop support unit etc. Someone you've never heard of in another office in a different timezone decides what software will be packaged for the self-service request system. You don't just have a word with your boss. Maybe it's different at a software company like Oracle than at a bank. (btw I'd move this to chat but I can't access that at work.)

Comment: @William Robertson I am working for bank too, and I know that. There is software installed on all stations that block the launch of any programs from unknown sources. But when I politely ask the security department to pull a program into exceptions and justify that I need it for work, they do not have problems for various versions of tools such as SQL-Developer, Eclipse, JBoss, maven, git, etc. that are available from trusted sources.

Comment: I can't give too many details except to say that the policies are fairly strict ... and with good reason. It can be annoying but the job has it's virtues also.

Answer (score 1):

Time to upgrade.

Using current version, 17.4 - which is 4 years newer than version 4.0 - this works as expected.

Query data.

Export to INSERT.

[image]

Went to clipboard, let's paste that back to the worksheet...and inspect the date format to what we have in preferences.

[image]

DATE formats defined in NLS parameters, match.

Feel free to reply with what you see differently if you're taking a different path - there are so many different ways to do an EXPORT - but all of them should honor NLS DATE FORMAT in preferences when dealing with DATEs.

If you can't upgrade, try this - a manual INSERT generation using the format hint.

`select /*insert*/ to_char(hire_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS') hiredate from employees`;

Comment: It works as expected on 4.1, the version I use. Could this have changed between 4.0 (the OP’s version) and 4.1?

Comment: if there was a bug, @mathguy, yes. Answering question for software released in 2013 is fun though

Comment: It should also generate the third argument: `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=<settings from SQL Developer>' to make export language-agnostic. My NLS settings will generate `ЯНВ` for `01` instead of `JAN` (though, I always set date format to ISO in all my IDE regardless of DBMS)

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded version 4.0.3 (4.0.3.16.84) from [this official link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-downloads-403-2529784.html)
[image]

---

I changed NLS parameters in this way:
[image]

---

The export of table having DATE/TIMESTAMP/TIMESTAMPTZ columns **worked fine**:

```
SET DEFINE OFF;

Insert into TEST.DAT (X,D,T,TZ) values (
     1,
     to_date('23-FEB-2018 22.24.15','DD-MON-RRRR HH24.MI.SS'),
     to_timestamp('23-FEB-18 10.24.15.662000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),
     to_timestamp_tz('24-FEB-18 05.44.25.000000000 AM EUROPE/BELGRADE','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR')
);
```

Maybe you are allowed to download the same version from Oracle's site ? 
It seems that this version includes bug fixes.

Answer (score 0):

thanks so much for the help. I'm not sure 100% sure what happen, but I tried to reproduce the issue again today and it seems to be working as expected sans upgrade (or even a restart).

Thanks anyway!